# How to delete a line of the text file from the output of checklist

Tags: bash

I have a text file:

```
$100 Birthday
$500 Laptop
$50 Phone
```

I created a --checklist from the text file

```
[ ] $100 Birthday
[*] $500 Laptop
[*] $50 Phone
```

the output is `$100 $50`

How can I delete the line of $100 and $50 in the text file, please?

The expected output of text file:

```
$100 Birthday
```

Thank you!

Comment: @alecxs Thank you so much, but I am new to bash. Could you give me more specific information, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `grep` and `cut`

```
grep -xf <(grep '\[ ]' file2.txt | cut -d\  -f3-) file1.txt
```

with `grep` and `sed`

```
grep -xf <(sed -rn 's/\[ ]\s+(.*)/\1/p' file2.txt) file1.txt
```

### explanation

use `grep` to select lines from text file

```
$ grep Birthday file1.txt
100 Birthday
```

`cut` will split line into columns. `-f 2` will print only 2nd column but `-f 2-` will print everything from 2nd column. as delimiter `-d` whitespace `' '`  is used here (some character must escaped with `\`)
and we can use pipe `|` as input (instead file)

```
$ echo one two three | cut -d \  -f 2-
two three
$ grep Birthday file1.txt | cut -d \  -f 2-
Birthday                            ^
                                    |
(note the two whitespaces)  --------+
```

assuming we have a text file `temp.txt`

```
$ cat temp.txt
Birthday
Laptop
Phone
```

`grep` can also read list of search patterns from another file as input instead

```
$ grep -f temp.txt file1.txt
100 Birthday
500 Laptop
50 Phone
```

or we print the file content with `cat` and redirect output with `<`

```
$ grep -f <(cat temp.txt) file1.txt
100 Birthday
500 Laptop
50 Phone
```

Now let's generate `temp.txt` from checklist. You only want grep lines containing `[ ]` and cut starting from 3rd column (again some characters have special meaning and must therefore escaped `\[`)

```
$ grep '\[ ]' file2.txt
[ ] 100 Birthday
$ grep '\[ ]' file2.txt | cut -d\ -f3-
100 Birthday
```

You don't need `temp.txt` and can therefore redirect list straight to `grep -f` what is called process substitution `<(...)`

```
$ grep -f <(grep '\[ ]' file2.txt | cut -d\  -f3-) file1.txt
100 Birthday
```

`grep` read all lines from `temp.txt` as PATTERN and some characters have special meaning for regex. `^` stands for begin of line and `$` for end of line. To be nitpicky correct search pattern should therefore be `'^100 Birthday$'` so it won't match **"1100 Birthday 2"**.
You might have noticed that I dropped the **$** currency in your input files for reason. You can keep it, but tell `grep` to take all input literally with `-F` and(/or?) `-x` flag which will search for whole line **"100 Birthday"** (no regex for line start/ending needed)

---

**`sed [OPTION] 's/regexp/replacement/command' [file]`**

`sed` is more common when it comes to text editing. instead `grep` `|` `cut` we can do it from one single command:
`grep '\[ ]' | cut -f3-` and `sed 's/\[ ] *//'`
are basically targeting the same lines and delete `[ ]` from it.
There are however some extra flags required, because `sed` is text editor and will stream the whole file by default. to emulate `grep`'s behavior we use
`-n` **option** to suppress the input
`p` **command** to print only changes

and for **regexp**
`\[ ]` (text to replace)
`' *'` = `' '` (whitespace) + `*` (star)
meaning: repeated previous character 0 or more times, in particulary all trailing whitespaces

(**replacement** is empty because we want just delete)

so working similar `sed` command will look like this

```
sed -n 's/\[ ] *//p' file2.txt
```

And that's in my opinion all it takes for a checklist. You have however two redundant files and want match your cloned checklist against original file, so let me show you more complicated things.

---

Instead of deleting the checkbox let's output captured groups. This pseudo code will explain it better than me. `\1` is for first capture group `( )` and so on (kinda internal variables)

```
$ sed 's/(aaa)b(ccc)dd/\1/'
aaa
$ sed 's/(aaa)b(ccc)dd/\2/'
ccc
$ sed 's/(aaa)b(ccc)dd/\1 \2/'
aaa ccc
$ sed 's/(aaa)b(ccc)dd/lets \1 replace \2 this/'
lets aaa replace ccc this
```

so in this example `sed 's/\[ ] (.*)/\1/'` we use for **regexp**
`\[ ]` (text to replace)
`' '` (trailing whitespace)
and inside the first capture group `( )` the desired **"100 Birthday"**
`.*` = `.` (dot) + `*` (star)
meaning: repeated previous character 0 or more times (in particulary a dot here)
but the dot `.` itself is regex for ANY char now (special meaning)
so the capture group is all the rest of line

and for **replacement** we use (only)
`\1` first capture group

```
$ sed -n 's/\[ ] (.*)/\1/p' file2.txt
100 Birthday
```

But there is more :)

Instead of matching only `' '` whitespace there exist another regex with special meaning (extended regex)
`\s` will match whitespace and tab
`+` repeated previous character **1** or more times (note the difference to `*` 0 or more times)
`\s+` will match a series of spaces
and to make it work we need one more flag
`-r` use extended regular expressions

so with this command you can extract all search patterns from your cloned checklist...

```
$ sed -rn 's/\[ ]\s+(.*)/\1/p' file2.txt
100 Birthday
```

...and finally let it run against your original file (without the need of `temp.txt`)

```
$ grep -xf <(sed -rn 's/\[ ]\s+(.*)/\1/p' file2.txt) file1.txt
100 Birthday
```